# Choose files for upload programmatically

Tags: fine-uploader

Is it possible to choose the files to upload programmatically? I have files in a known path that I want to upload automatically without any user intervention.

Comment: If that is from a browser I really hope that the answer is still 'No, that can't be done and if it could it would be a huge security flaw'

Comment: Well, sure it is, fine-uploader is a Javascript plugin for file uploading

Comment: In that case the last part of my comment stands!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [programmatically passing FineUploader the location of the file to upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362703/programmatically-passing-fineuploader-the-location-of-the-file-to-upload)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot select files via client-side javascript. The user will at the very least need to drag and drop or select which file(s) they wish to upload. From there, you can programmatically control them as File-like objects.