# programmatically passing FineUploader the location of the file to upload

Tags: fine-uploader

We have prototyped a client-side program that lets users select a local folder, creates a zip, then lets the local browser know about the zip file location via a local web socket.  The intention is to then tell fineUploader about this new zip file location, so that it can immediately start the upload process.

But I'm not clear how to make this last part of the handoff.  I just saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067282/how-to-create-a-file-blob-for-use-with-fine-uploader-api) which sounds concerning.

Is there any way?  If not, how might we make an acceptable user experience given that the user has selected a dir, it has been zipped for them, and we want the fineUploader component to process the upload?

Thanks!

Stu

Comment: Is this zip file stored on the local user's file system? Is the zip file itself accessible via HTTP or web sockets?

Comment: Yes, it is on the local user filesystem.  We wrote a tiny websocket server running as a java app, that the local page talks to.  It prompts the user via a swing file chooser, then starts a-zipping, sending progress and final status (zip location) over the websocket channel.

Comment: Is the zip file itself accessible via HTTP or web sockets?

Comment: We're using it to send files to S3 btw.  ...I'd even settle for a solution that double prompted the user, after performing the zip operation, if fineUploader prompted them to select the zip file that was just created.  It's a little goofy but would be functional.  Though of course if there's a way to initiate the fineUploader upload from the wss plumbing somehow, that would be preferred

Comment: Not currently, but it could be.  The wss server could expose it via either of those mechanisms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code running in the browser is not able to access your filesystem directly. If you want to upload files, your users will have to manually select these files via drag-and-drop or an `<input type="file">` chooser dialog.

However, if the zip file is accessible via HTTP or WS, this is possible. Assuming HTTP, you can make an ajax GET request for the zip file, [read it into a `Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data), and then send this `Blob` to Fine Uploader via the [`addFiles` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addFiles). If you're reading the file over WS, you'll need to take the returned data and convert it to a `Blob` using `FileReader`.

Note that this is not possible in browsers older than IE10.

Comment: Is this likely to have memory issues for large files?  As in, if the zip is actually 500mb, is there way to avoid holding all of the streamed file data in memory?  I understand S3 needs a content length so the file has to get completely transferred through the websocket first to the local page, then fineUploader would stream the data to S3.  Wondering if there's anything I should think about doing, or using a particular API for reading from the websocket, that might minimize memory footprint for large files?

Comment: Yes, this is likely to have memory issues for large files. There is no reasonable way to avoid this. In all honesty, instead of zipping the file server-side, then transferring the file to the browser, just to send the file to a different server, you should instead send the zip file to its final destination server-side.

Comment: I didn't properly explain the use case.  Our prototype actually zips the files client-side, where the user browser is.  User clicks an 'upload' button, which wakes up a  tiny java app listening via websockets.  User is prompted to select the directory to upload in a swing file chooser.  Upon selection, the java app does the zipping to the local filesystem.  ...thinking now how to get that into S3.

Comment: Since fineUploader has worked so well for us with single files, I was maybe inappropriately shoehorning this use case into fineUploader.  Maybe better to just have the client do the upload to S3 as well?  End users may have proxies in place, I guess I'd need to figure out how to configure the S3 client to use the proxy that the browser will already know about (one reason continuing down fineUploader path seemed appealing).

Comment: All of this (zipping) happens outside of the browser via a Java Applet, effectively server-side. I'd have the Java app then turn around and upload to S3. This is tangential, but it's going to become nearly impossible to support Java Applets in any browser in the near future. You should begin designing a new solution.

Comment: Not an applet, this websocket listener would be delivered via an installer and running as a separate process.  NOT excited about the sol'n for sure. Hoping browser capabilities expand to support proper dir upload later. You have nice support for Chrome DnD, but it still seems like a gap caused by the spec

Comment: Ah I see. Well, my suggestion to send the zip file via this sep Java process stands. The Filesystem API, which made directory uploads via DnD possible is a dead spec. The W3C deprecated it, so it will never be implemented in any other browser. Though is talk of a new spec to address this. Nothing formal yet though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127137/discussion-between-stu2-and-ray-nicholus).